# Como pegar um PDF não explícito na Web utilizando PHP

Tags: php, pdf

Bem, estou tentando fazer o uso de um PDF através do seu link. Estou utilizando uma biblioteca chamada PDF Parser. O problema é que o PDF não tem um link direto. Ao acessar o link, é passada uma chave como parâmetro e ele devolve o PDF.

Eis o link: http://diario.ac.gov.br/download.php?arquivo=KEQxQHI3IyEpRE8xNDY4NjkxNjk5OTQwMi5wZGY=

No meu código estou fazendo:

```
$pdf = $parser->parseFile('http://diario.ac.gov.br/download.php?arquivo=KEQxQHI3IyEpRE8xNDY4NjkxNjk5OTQwMi5wZGY');
```

E ele dá conexão reiniciada. Porém se eu utilizo um link de acesso direto ao PDF, funciona normalmente, da forma a seguir:

```
$pdf = $parser->parseFile('http://cnd.fgv.br/sites/cnd.fgv.br/files/teste_2.pdf');
```

Como faço para conseguir obter esse PDF?

Comment: Aqui aparenta normal, consegui baixar o PDF sem problemas

Comment: O mesmo aqui, fiz um wget e funcionou sem problemas. (wget http://diario.ac.gov.br/download.php?arquivo=KEQxQHI3IyEpRE8xNDY4NjkxNjk5OTQwMi5wZGY= -O teste.pdf)

Comment: @Bacco qual função utilizou? Tento fazer isso dentro do código PHP mesmo.

Comment: @cantoni, o wget se utiliza no prompt de comando ou no próprio código? (não sou muito familiarizado com o PHP)

Comment: Estou tentando passar o valor para uma variável pra poder passar para o método do PDF Parser.

Comment: Os dois links funcionam da mesma maneira pra mim (obtendo programaticamente). Sugeriria você baixar os dados pelo PHP e salvar em disco pra fins de teste e ver se o problema persiste. Provavelmente seu problema é timeout. Experimente executar o PHP pela linha de comando e ver se o problema continua.

Comment: Sim, entendi @JoãoNeto. Testei com wget na linha de comando só por curiosidade. Como funciona lá, você pode eliminar qualquer mistério em relação ao link em si.

Comment: Hmmm, entendi. Então vou tentar ver outra solução. Pois com o link direto ele abre na hora, já o outro link dá apenas conexão reiniciada. Seria algum problema em relação a demora da requisição por parte do servidor (diario.ac.gov.br)? Pois no meu PHP já setei o tempo de limite para alguns minutos.

Comment: Como vc setou o tempo limite? Se não mudar a config do PHP, não tem como passar do máximo na hora do runtime.

Comment: @bacco set_time_limit(250);

Comment: isso ai pode não ser respeitado. dependendo da config, nao tem como passar do limite do php.ini

Comment: Hmm, então vou alterar aqui no php e testar.

Comment: Coloquei aqui no PHP também o tempo máximo e mesmo assim a conexão foi reiniciada.

Comment: lembdando que tem o max_execution_time e tambem tem o time limit do servidor web. Geralmente mexer nestas coisas não é a solução correta. Teste via linha de comando. Inclusive, pq se for usar isso na prática, compensa fazer um script em BG pra fazer isso, sem passar pelo servidor web.

Comment: Então acho que vou usar a linha de comando, baixar o pdf para o servidor e então abri-lo diretamente. Seria melhor dessa forma?

Comment: quis dizer de rodar o PHP em BG. De qq forma, antes de mais nada é bom vc testar se é isso mesmo pra poder dar qq passo. Se chamando esse PHP diretamente não der o erro, ao menos descobriu a causa

Comment: Entendi @Bacco, vou testar! Valeu!